# can push/pull from terminal not from VS Code, error: c:\\ ...\askpass.sh line 3: C:\...Code.exe: command not found; fatal: Authentication failed for

Tags: git

As title says I have a private git repo on my local network and can push/pull no problem from terminal outside VS Code but when I try from the integrated terminal (PowerShell) I get this error:

```
c:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh: line 3: C:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Loc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe: command not found
c:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh: line 3: C:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Loc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe: command not found
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myprivateLocalRepo'
```

I tried searching but I couldn't seem to find an issue with this error.

When I run `git config credential.helper` I get "manager-core" and have tried running `git config --global credential.helper wincred` but doesn't seem to help.

Based off of the additional info below I believe `C:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Loc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe` should be evaluated to `C:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe` as I have a Code.exe in that Folder/Directory but I'm not sure how to get it to evaluate to that.

Any help is greatly appreciated. It's not a serious issue as I can just use git from an outside terminal but it would be nice to get resolved.

Additional info :

Folder/Directory `C:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Loc` does not exist

c:\Users\Artyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\askpass.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_PIPE=`mktemp`
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE="1" VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_PIPE="$VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_PIPE" "$VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE" "$VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN" $*
cat $VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_PIPE
rm $VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_PIPE
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem that was fixed by going into VSC Preferences > Settings and searching for "terminal". Then under Extensions > Git, there is a setting "Git: Terminal Authentication", I unchecked and restarted my terminal and the error went away.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it dont remember how as it was 2 months ago now but I appreciate the reply

Comment: Worked for me after I rechecked "Git: Terminal Authentication" again afterwards. Not sure why it stopped working in the first place.